# Does the Pi 3A+ really support Kodi, when used for continuous display of photos and videos in a folder?

Tags: pi-3a+

I have tried OSMC, OpenElec and Kodi installed on Raspbian Bullseye, and with all of them the display will freeze or the program will reboot after some time.  I have an autoexec.py file which will start a continuous slideshow of photos and videos in a folder, Kodi is set to random display.  The same application seems to run okay with 3B+.  Are there specific settings in boot/config.txt that are necessary for the 3A+ as compared to 3B+?

[How to play 720p/1080p videos on Raspberry Pi 3 A+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101792/how-to-play-720p-1080p-videos-on-raspberry-pi-3-a)

This seemed to indicate that the 3A+ could run Kodi well, but this is an old post.

Comment: perhaps it's your autoexec.py file that is somehow the issue

Comment: All that the autoexec,py file does is to setup the path for the slideshow and start it.

Comment: the TL;DR ... try LibreElec - sorry, just noticed the question is about the 3A+ - personally, I think Kodi on Raspberry Pi OS is probably too much for the 3A+ due to its lower memory - so, Bullseye and OSMC (which is just Raspberry Pi OS with Kodi pre-installed for you) won't work very well. OpenElec used to be OK, but I switched to LibreElec as I found it to have superior performance on a Pi 3B - though, that was 5 years ago now, so things could have changed ...

Comment: Actually, I did test with LibreElec, not OpenElec as mentioned earlier. That works better, but eventually that also freezes, or restarts. The 512MB RAM probably is just not enough for playing large videos, unless there are some specific settings for the 3A+ which will prevent the problem.  Thanks.